# Какова синтаксическая принадлежность атрибутов data в HTML?

Tags: html, синтаксис, семантика

Вопрос касается `data-` атрибутов в синтаксисе языка html?

Для чего используется такой атрибут, каковы его свойства и как с ним работать? Под работой понимается оперирование им в CSS и JavaScript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Из всех перечисленных тегов вопроса атрибуты есть только в html, а в js (в DOM) есть dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 спроектирован с возможностью расширения данных ассоциированных с каким-либо элементом, но в то же время не обязательно имеющих определённое значение. data-* атрибуты позволяют хранить дополнительную информацию в стандартных элементах HTML, без хаков вроде нестандартных атрибутов, лишних DOM-свойств или Node.setUserData() (en-US).

## Синтаксис HTML

Синтаксис прост — любой атрибут, чьё имя начинается с data-, является data-* атрибутом. Предположим у нас имеется статья и мы хотим сохранить дополнительную информацию без визуального представления. Для этого можно использовать data-атрибуты:

```
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

## Доступ в JavaScript

Чтение data-атрибутов в JavaScript осуществляется также просто. Для этого можно использовать метод `getAttribute()` с параметром, равным полному имени атрибута. Но есть и более простой способ, используя объект `dataset`.

Чтобы получить `data-`атрибут можно взять свойство объекта `dataset` с именем, равным части имени атрибута после `data-` (обратите внимание, что дефисы в имени преобразуются в camelCase).

```
var article = document.getElementById('electriccars');

article.dataset.columns // "3"
article.dataset.indexNumber // "12314"
article.dataset.parent // "cars"
```

Каждое свойство является строкой и может быть прочитано и записано. В приведённом выше примере выполнение кода `article.dataset.columns = 5` приведёт к тому, что новое значение атрибута станет равным `"5"`.

## Проблемы

Не храните данные, которые должны быть видимы и доступны в `data-`атрибутах. Дело в том, что вспомогательная техника (assistive technology) может не получить к ним доступ. В дополнение, поисковые роботы не индексируют данные, содержащиеся в `data-`атрибутах.

Источник: [Использование data-* атрибутов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF_%D0%B2_javascript)

Дополнительная информация: [Полное руководство по HTML-атрибутам data-*](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/490626/)